# How to use ConcurrentDictionary and Task in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, task

I am having some issues where  `projectLogDict` is not updating the `ImageCount` . If you look at the code below, I have `var drawingCount` and `var imageCount` which I add to the `Task.WhenAll`.

The problem is that the `imageCount` value never seems to get updated in `projectLogDict`. However if I comment out the `var drawingCount`, the `imageCount` value works and gets updated in `projectLogDict`

I'm not sure why both values can't be updated in `projectLogDict`.

Is there a way to update both `drawingCount` and `imageCount` and add it to the `projectLogDict` ?

```
public async Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, ProjectLogs>> GetProjectFiles(ConcurrentDictionary<string, ProjectLogs> projectLogDict)
{
    var locations = await _test.GetAllLocations().ConfigureAwait(false);
    foreach(var branch in locations)
    {
        var projects = await _test.GetLocationProjectsAsync(branch).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var task = new List<Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, ProjectLogs>>>();
        var taskTwo = new List<Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, ProjectLogs>>>();

        foreach (var project in projects)
        {
            var drawingCount = GetDrawingCount(project.Id);
            var imageCount = GetImageCount(project.Id);
            taskTwo.Add(imageCount);
            task.Add(drawingCount);

        }

        var x = await Task.WhenAll(task.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var y = await Task.WhenAll(taskTwo.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return projectLogDict;
}



public async Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, ProjectLogs>> GetImageCount(string projectId)
{
    var files = await _test.GetUploadFilesAsync(projectId, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
    projectLogDict.AddOrUpdate(projectId, new ProjectLogs { ImageCount = file.count() }, (key, value) => value = new ProjectLogs { ImageCount = file.count() });
    
    return projectLogDict;
}



public async Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, ProjectLogs>> GetDrawingCount(string projectId )
{
    
    var drawingCount = await _test.GetItemsDrawing(projectId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    projectLogDict.AddOrUpdate(projectId, new ProjectLogs { DrawingCount = drawingCount.Count() }, (key, value) => value = new ProjectLogs { DrawingCount = drawingCount.Count() });
    
    return projectLogDict;
    
}
```

Comment: You don't need a ConcurrentDictionary as you are doing no concurrent writes to your dictionary. Also, I would expect that `GetDrawingCount` and `GetImageCount` have a `projectLogDict` argument. It's unclear where they even get their projectLogDict from and if it even is the same as the one `GetProjectFiles` receives. This is just waiting for some nasty suprises to be happing where you think you are working on the same dictionary, but you actually aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the second `AddOrUpdate` runs, if will not `Add` as the `projectId` key already exists, so it will run the `updateValueFactory` delegate. This is where your issue is. For both calls, you are only setting the one property, returning the new class which means you are constantly overriding what is already in your dictionary.

To solve this, you need to take into account `value` in your delegate and set the corresponding property :

```
projectLogDict.AddOrUpdate(projectId, new ProjectLogs { ImageCount = file.count() }, (key, value) => new ProjectLogs { ImageCount = file.count(), DrawingCount = value.DrawingCount });
```

and

```
projectLogDict.AddOrUpdate(projectId, new ProjectLogs { DrawingCount = drawingCount.Count() }, (key, value) => new ProjectLogs { DrawingCount = drawingCount.Count(), ImageCount = value.ImageCount });
```